# How to get the complete list of recently updated wiki articles?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Wikipedia provides RSS feed for recently changed articles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:RecentChanges&feed=rss

This feed returns 50 records maximum.
Seems like it is updated once per 10-15 seconds. It means that where will be lost records in case of sequential calls if there were more than 50 articles updated within ~15 seconds time window.

Is there any way to receive complete list of changes or at least do significantly better than this?

In general I'd like to receive all updates once puller started, or subscribe to a stream of events.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [RecentChanges API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:RecentChanges) or [EventStreams web service](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/EventStreams).